# Python: using loop for specific elements of array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, integer

I want to make a new array that has the original array's elements changed-- but I want to make the change different per elements in the original array like if the 3<=element is <6, take -1 from the original array... is this possible?

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in array:
    if i < 3:
        arrayn = array
    elif i < 6:
        arrayn = array - 1
    elif i < 10:
        arrayn = array - 2
print(arrayn)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    arrayn = array - 1
             ~~~~~~^~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

With that example, my ideal would've been:

```
0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the full traceback error as text and not as an image.  Also please include the sample input and expected output.  Cursory glance, ```array - 1``` isn't correct.

Comment: Shouldn't your ideal be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10`.  10 is not less than 10.

Comment: `array - 1` is an error.  You can't subtract an integer from a list.  Please explain what you intended here.

Comment: You should read a Python tutorial before attempting to write Python programs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  It's easiest to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```py
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

arrayn = [a if a < 3 else a-1 if a < 6 else a-2 if a < 10 else a
          for a in array]

print(arrayn)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]
```

Note: 10 is not less than 10, so the "ideal" example in the question is incorrect.

Comment: If I have another array such as Arrey[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] with the number of indicies that correspond to how many are in array, and I would like to do a similar operation of loop, but this time involving indices from the different array that corresponds to each other, how should i do that... Corresponding, I meant the [] number, like Array[1] *Arrey[1]. E.g.  say  for indices over 4 in array Array, I want Array*Arrey but for else, I want Array/Arrey. Sorry if this is also very basic...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you hitting this error?

It's because *you* are saying "Subtract 1 from the array." But in Python parlance, this is actually "Subtract 1 from every element in the array."

Subtracting an integer from a list raises an exception because they are incompatible types.

```py
a = [1]

a - 1
TypeError

# the correct syntax
a[0] = a[0] - 1
```

Since you are modifying the list while iterating over it, you need access to both the indices and elements. This is a good place to introduce `enumerate`, which will produce pairs of `(index, value)` as you iterate over it:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]

for i, value in enumerate(x):
    print(i, value)

0 1 # prints the pair here
1 2
2 3
```

Next, you'll also want to set the value in your original array using that index. Modifying your original code

```py
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i, value in enumerate(array):
    if value < 3:
        array[i] = value
    elif value < 6:
        # set the new value at the index
        array[i] = value - 1
    elif value < 10:
        # set the new value here
        array[i] = value - 2

print(array)
```

If you need a new array rather than modifying the one you started with, you can append to a new list like so:

```py
# set your new one here
new_array = []

# you aren't modifying the original anymore,
# so you can drop the enumerate
for value in array:
    if value < 3:
        new_array.append(value)
    elif value < 6:
        new_array.append(value - 1)
    elif value < 10:
        new_array.append(value - 2)
    else:
        # catch everything else
        new_array.append(value)
```

Comment: thank you very much; that was so comprehensive

Comment: If I have another array such as Arrey[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] with the number of indicies that correspond to how many are in array, and I would like to do a similar operation of loop, but this time involving indices from the different array that corresponds to each other, how should i do that... Corresponding, I meant the [] number, like Array[1] *Arrey[1]. E.g.  say  for indices over 4 in array Array, I want Array*Arrey but for else, I want Array/Arrey. Sorry if this is also very basic...

Comment: You complicated it a little bit @C.Nivs , as shows below it can be done in really easier way than this.

Comment: But I do appreciate the lesson you gave him! Hope he will use it fully.

Comment: @JohnyCapo I'd disagree here. The first steps are understanding how iteration works. The list comprehension may fit on a single line, but I wouldn't say it's necessarily easier to read or maintain. List comprehensions are important, but walk before you run